# What is the difference between 利润， 利益，盈利？

Tags: difference

I have noticed that all of them mean benefit or profit in English.

Can someone help me understand when to use each word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“利润” is the spread between interest and paid, and is always used in economy.

“利益” is the benefit that people gain from what they are doing or are going to do.

“盈利” is similar to “利润”. But "利润" usually be used as a noun,“盈利” can be used a noun, an adjective and a verb.

For example:

1.公司今年的**利润**是10,000,000，明年目标是**盈利**100,000,000。

Translate into English：

The company's profits is 10,000,000 this year, and their goal is gain 100,000,000 next year.

“利润” is used as a noun, and “盈利” is used as a verb in this sentence.

2.苹果是去年唯一一家**盈利**的公司。

Apple is the only profitable company last year.

“盈利” is used as an adjective here.

3.**盈利**对一家上市公司来说很重要。

Profits is important to the listed company.

“盈利” is used as a noun in this sentence.